# Foot pain during all exercise - HIIT alternatives?

Tags: hiit, foot-pain

I'm at a loss for what to do. For a number of years now the outer underside of both of my feet cause me a lot if pain during excercise - running, cross trainer, walking!! I've tried different footwear & been to a podiatrist but no answers yet.

I've found something online which I think it could be - lateral column overload. But this has not been diagnosed.

A week ago I started a 3 month food & fitness program in a bid to lose some of my extra weight (I'd like to lose about 4 stone). So far I've found the good difficult but manageable & am starting to feel marginally healthier.

However I'm required to do 4 short HIIT workouts per week & my foot pain is causing me a real problem. My feet are extremely painful after about 10 mins of exercising & only gradually improve after about 15 mins of rest.

Can anyone advise about HIIT exercises that won't put pressure on my feet?? 
Or has anyone heard of/had a similar condition?

Thanks for your help, Jenny

Comment: Trying swimming sprints in the pool. It works the whole body and there is zero impact on the feet.

Comment: Yes that could be worth a try, thanks. Hadn't seen swimming suggested as HIIT but I guess it works the same way as any exercises. I might look a bit loony going hell for leather in the pool every now and then though! ;)

Comment: Have you been checked for Plantar fasciitis?

Comment: As @Michael suggest swimming sprints are one way to do HIIT without aggravating foot pain.  You can also [run in water](http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/6894/what-is-the-a-proper-way-to-pool-run). I can get an effective Tabata HIIT workout this way. A stationary or recumbent cycle may also be easier on your foot.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have access to a rower?

Obviously you are exerting force through your feet on a rower but it is not an impact like running. If you do have access to one I recommend learning good technique and then giving it a few attempts (I can provide a link to a video tutorial if you're interested).

EDIT : I should also add that it could be your running style. I know you said they hurt when doing things other than running, but one thing could be the source and then doing other activities results in pain because you're feet have not had time to heal. So, you may wish to examine your running style and seek making changes. I recommend looking up the Pose Technique by Dr Romanov to see if "re-learning" how to run well can help you.

EDIT : So this is a great rowing technique tutorial for a beginner. There is a bit of background noise, I hope you don't mind that. Take things easy at first, and pay attention to each piece of the technique. If you have further questions, I am happy to answer or provide additional videos that go into more detail. Let us all know how you progress with your foot pain diagnosis and what you find that works for you. 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E_-7VQpPd54

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I currently work out at home as I have a young child which makes it difficult to find time to go out 4 times a week. However I've been thinking about joining a gym so I have access to other equipment - I was thinking of the bikes but rowers would be good too. I'll have a look at the pose technique, as I would really love to run. The rowing link would be useful, thank you.

Comment: Using a rower may not be a good alternative depending on the diagnosis. When performed correctly, you drive with your feet on the rower. It is not a pulling exercise.